# Firebase-Database: deny in general but allow for specific path

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I try to generate my Firebase-DB Rules and want to deny writing without Authentication in general and only allow it for a specific path. It gets published correctly but it does not work.
http://myproject.firebaseio.com/test/foo

```
{ 
   "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": "auth != null",
     "foo":{
       ".write": "true"      
     } 
   } 
}
```

UPDATE 1
OK, I found out that Rule-Cascading is making it impossible how I did it above, because

```
".write": "auth != null"
```

is preventing me from writing. How can I avoid that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firebase rules cascade from the top down, so there's no way to block writing at a higher level, but allow it at a lower one. Here's a note [right from the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade):

> Note: Shallower security rules override rules at deeper paths. Child
>   rules can only grant additional privileges to what parent nodes have
>   already declared. They cannot revoke a read or write privilege.

You may need to restructure your data so that the `foo` object is at the top-level, which would let you have a different write rule on it.

Another option is to simply remove the write rule at the root and add it to any other root-level items that require an authenticated user.

Comment: you are right, re-structuring my data did the trick. I will mark that as the correct answer. Thanks Sam